# Android SDK fails to install. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, android

I face problem when I want to add new sdk. these are my errors:

The project wasn't generated by 'android' tool.

The system cannot find the file specified.
Error: Error parsing the sdk.
Error: com/google/common/collect/Multimap
Error: Unable to parse SDK content.

what's my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Find the folder named: .android

This folder can be located in your Windows user directory, for example in Windows 7 or 8:

C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME.android

Step 2. Delete this folder .android

Step 3. Restart Eclipse and your problem will be solved.

hopefully... if not reinstall you eclipse